# Creating a slide menu with a split view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

My app is a simple Master-Detail applciation, based on a Split View Controller (for the iPhone 6+). The Master View is listing the news of my Web Site, and the Detail View is showing the news, embedded in a UIWebView.

I'm trying to add a side menu (like [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController)), but I can't find an API fully fonctionable with my app. Do you have any idea of an API compatible with StoryBoards and a Split View ?

Or maybe do you have an idea on how to make compatible ECSlidingViewController with a Split View ? I can't make it, I have a fatal error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ECSlidingViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ee133d0'
```

[The Storyboard of my app](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/40/1412450354-capture-d-ecran-2014-10-04-a-21-13-10.png).

Thanks in advance.